# Define boost signal in terms of a boost::function?

Tags: c++, boost

Normally, you define a `boost::signals2::signal` like so:

```
typedef boost::signals2::signal<void (int)> MySignalType;
MySignalType mySignal;
```

and then you can use `MySignalType::slot_function_type` to get the function signature compatible with that signal.

I, however, am trying to do the opposite.

I have existing code that doesn't use Boost signals.  Instead, the code passes around a `boost::function` and calls it back to "signal" some event.  I want to create a `boost::signals2::signal` **in terms of** the existing `boost::function`.  I tried the most intuitive combination:

```
typedef boost::function<void (int)> MyFunctionType;
typedef boost::signals2::signal<MyFunctionType> MySignalType;
```

But this is rejected by the compiler. I would be amazed if this wasn't possible, since both are Boost packages. My best guess is that a `boost::function` object (or typedef) has its own internal typedef similar in purpose to `slot_function_type` that is usable where a pure function signature is required, but I didn't find anything like this in [boost::function documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/function.html).

I tried searching for a similar Q&A, as well as skimming Boost documentation, and haven't found anyone doing the same thing.

Is there a way to define a Boost signal in terms of an existing Boost function?

Thanks.

Comment: Your last code chunk is at least missing a `>`.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed. I retyped the code for this question, so this isn't the cause of the original problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, we have no way of knowing that you didn't make similar mistakes elsewhere. Please post your testcase _verbatim_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to extract signature from boost::function then you can try something like this:

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct get_arg;

template<template<typename> class Func,typename Sig>
struct get_arg< Func<Sig> >
{
    typedef Sig type;
};

int main()
{
    typedef boost::function<void()> F;
    signals2::signal< get_arg<F>::type > signal;
}
```

---

EDIT:

> Very interesting. Can you point me to someplace that explains what your code does and how you came up with it?

get_arg is class template, which extracts template argument from its argument (from template argument of get_arg).

In other words it is [Metafunction](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Metafunction) - it is literally function which operates on types (while normal functions operates on values).

```
template<template<typename> class Func,typename Sig>
struct get_arg< Func<Sig> >
```

This syntax is [partial specialization](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fpartial_specialization.htm) of get_arg class template

```
template<typename> class Func
```

This syntax is [template template parameter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Ftemplate_template_arguments.htm).

```
typedef Sig type;
```

By convention, result of Metafunction is nested "type" member.

Usage is:

```
get_arg< SomeClassTemplate<SomeType> >::type
```

Which results in **SomeType**

For additional info, look at following books:

1. Modern C++ Design: Generic Programming and Design Patterns Applied. by Andrei Alexandrescu
2. C++ Template Metaprogramming: Concepts, Tools, and Techniques from Boost and Beyond. By David Abrahams and Aleksey Gurtovoy

Comment: Very interesting.  Can you point me to someplace that explains what your code does and how you came up with it?